# RAM Error running the Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

After installing the Tensorflow Object Detection API and following all the instructions, I started training with my own dataset. Very quickly the program began to use all the RAM and the process was killed. I have read all the post available on this subject and nobody seems to have an answer. This is another attempt at trying to figure out what is the cause of  this problem.

Computer specs:

1. 12 GB RAM
2. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
3. tensorflow-gpu
4. NVIDIA GTX 1070 - 8.0 GB

The log was:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
Killed
```

From what others are writing it is definitely a memory usage problem. Any help is well received.

Comment: What makes you think that this is because you are running out of RAM? Have you checked the output of (h)top?

Comment: So I have been monitoring the the cpu and memory performance, and it takes all of the resources. And second there are various of other posts which present the same problem and all suggest the same issue, that it is a OOM issue.

Comment: Can you say what resolution your images are?

Comment: They are 960x1248.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by tweaking the config files.

[It turns out](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817#issuecomment-312136249) most of the RAM is consumed by the input queues. But since the data is in the super-fast tfrecord format, there is not need to keep that many examples prepared.

Depending on what model you use (SSD, Faster R-CNN), these settings would vary, since SSD can use higher batches that FRCNN (which basically uses batches of 1).

Identify or add the following in your config files and play with the numbers for the queues.

```
train_config: {
  # ... other settings  
  batch_size: 1 # this is for FRCNN
  batch_queue_capacity: 10
  num_batch_queue_threads: 4
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 5
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/path/to/train.tfrecord"
  }
  label_map_path: "/path/to/label/map.pbtxt"
  queue_capacity: 400
  min_after_dequeue: 200
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/path/to/eval.tfrecord"
  }
  label_map_path: "/path/to/label/map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  queue_capacity: 20
  min_after_dequeue: 10
  num_readers: 1
}
```

These and other settings were found out by inspecting the `.proto` files in `object_detection/protos` which describe all settings of the models.

Comment: Although this helped me to solve the problem. Are there any downsides to this. Since the input sequences are queued it should be a problem I guess.

Comment: if the numbers are too small and you have slow drive and/or CPUs, then your GPU utilisation will be lower, as it will be waiting for the next batch to be pre-processed. So watch `nvidia-smi` and if you see low gpu utilisation, benchmark the input pipeline (the problem may lie elsewhere, though).

Answer (score 1):

Check the dmesg. If it is an out of memory error, you can solve this by increasing your swap memory.

Increase your swap memory allocation by a lot, start your training, and see how much area you actually need for your specific issue. Then, you can fine tune the swap memory size.