# Tensorflow Object Detection API for custom dataset - Killed during training

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, object-detection-api

Training for object detection on custom dataset (images of shop fronts), for a single class (285 images in total), running locally on CPU, with 8GB RAM gets **killed** after a few steps.

I'm following this [blog](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) as a reference.

Here's the console log

```
(tensorflow) rajaram@rajaram-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/tensorflow/models$ python object_detection/train.py \
>     --logtostderr \
>     --pipeline_config_path=/home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_sf_train.config \
>     --train_dir=/home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py:607: all_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed after 2017-03-02.
Instructions for updating:
Please use tf.global_variables instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.121785: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.122313: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.123308: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.124144: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.124658: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-09-26 22:15:08.953929: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:697] Ignoring device specification /device:GPU:0 for node 'prefetch_queue_Dequeue' because the input edge from 'prefetch_queue' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /device:CPU:0
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.00238991
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 14.4365 (801.196 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 1.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2: loss = 12.9940 (173.981 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 2.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 3.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3: loss = 12.4866 (166.656 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 3.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:global step 4: loss = 11.2386 (162.260 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 4.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 4.
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 5.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 5: loss = 10.8210 (416.903 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 5.
Killed
(tensorflow) rajaram@rajaram-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/tensorflow/models$
```

### My thoughts and questions

1) **Are image sizes an issue**? - Distribution of my images are as follows:
<= 400x300 (5%), between 400x300 & 640x480 (22%), between 640x480 & 800x600 (63%) and > 800x600 (22%). Although images with dimensions around 400x300 would be good enough for recognition of shopboards, there's a skew towards larger resolutions in my dataset because the next step is text recognition on those boards.

- Is this thinking right?
- Should I resize the images to a smaller dimension (if yes - what dimensions are good) and re-do the annotation before starting the whole process again?

*I could train the Oxford-IIIT Pet data (~7.9k images - which took ~13 hours) for 2000 steps (num_steps = 2000 in train_config section of config file), without crashing or getting killed. So, I figure a mere 285 images should be able to run on the CPU itself.*

2) **Is swap memory an issue?** - I've also checked the other posts ([increase swap space suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150773/tensorflow-object-detection-training-killed-resource-starvation), [no follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833085/tensorflow-object-detection-killed-before-starting) & [another increase swap memory suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247292/ram-error-running-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api)) which are on similar lines but since I could train the Oxford-IIIT pet dataset on my current system settings, training as little as 285 images shouldn't kill the process.

- Is my thinking correct?
- If not and this is indeed a solution, then I need pointers and clear steps to do this.

---

I would like to know what's going wrong and get it running locally. I hope I have given sufficient information to get help. If not, please let me know what's needed.

```
                         ---------------------------
```

### **System information**

1. **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using:** tensorflow/models (haven't updated to the new folder structure yet)
2. **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow):** Yes - minimal changes (following [Dat Trans's
   template for my own data set - Github](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset))
3. **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):** Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
4. **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):** binary (into a virtual environment)
5. **TensorFlow version (use command below):** 1.3.0
6. **Bazel version (if compiling from source):** NA
7. **CUDA/cuDNN version:** NA
8. **GPU model and memory:** NA
9. **Exact command to reproduce:** python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=/home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_sf_train.config
   --train_dir=/home/rajaram/tensorflow/models/object_detection/models/sf_od_model/train

Comment: I have seen this on someone else's computer. In their case, it did seem to be an issue with swap memory running out. The size of the input images might not be as much of an issue as the batch sizes. Try reducing the batch sizes for both train and inference to something like 1. Even this might not be enough to get it to work properly. TensorFlow’s Object Detector API uses a lot of memory, even with batch sizes of 1 it cannot be run on a 6GB computer. I don't know if that additional 2GB you have will be enough.